# How does fread deal with trailing garbage when reaching the end of the file?

Tags: c, fread

I recently started dabbing in C again, a language I'm not particularly proficient at and, in fact, keep forgetting (I mostly code in Python). My idea here is to read data from a hypothetically large file as chunks and then process the data accordingly. For now, I'm simulating this by actually loading the whole file into a buffer of type short with fread. This method will be changed, since it would be a very bad idea for, say, a file that's 1 GB, I'd think. The end goal is to read a chunk as one, process, move the cursor, read another chunk and so on.

The file in question is 43 bytes and has the phrase "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog". This size is convenient because it's a prime number, so no matter how many bytes I split it into, there will always be trailing garbage (due to the buffer having leftover space?). Data processing in this case is just printing out the shorts as two chars after byte manipulation (see code below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_BUFF_SIZE 1024

long file_size(FILE *f) 
{
    if (fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END) != 0) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);     // Move cursor to the end
    long file_size = ftell(f);                              // Determine position to get file size
    rewind(f);

    return file_size;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    short buff[MAX_BUFF_SIZE] = {0};                        // Initialize to 0 remove trailing garbage
    char* filename  = argv[1];
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    if (fp) 
    {
        size_t size = sizeof(buff[0]);                      // Size in bytes of each chunk. Fixed to 2 bytes
        int nmemb = (file_size(fp) + size - 1) / size;      // Number of chunks to read from file
                                                            // (ceil f_size/size)
        printf("Should read at most %d chunks\n", nmemb);           

        short mask = 0xFF;                                  // Mask to take first or second byte

        size_t num_read = fread(buff, size, nmemb, fp); 

        printf("Read %lu chunks\n\n", num_read);            // Seems to have read more? Look into.

        for (int i=0; i<nmemb; i++) {
            char first_byte = buff[i] & mask;
            char second_byte = (buff[i] >> 8) & mask;       // Identity for 2 bytes. Keep mask for consistency

            printf("Chunk %02d: 0x%04x | %c %c\n",          // Remember little endian (bytes reversed) 
                    i, buff[i], first_byte, second_byte);         
        }
        fclose(fp);
    } else 
    {
        printf("File %s not found\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now yesterday, on printing out the last chunk of data I was getting "Chunk 21: 0xffff9567 | g". The last (first?) byte (0x67) is g, and I did expect some trailing garbage, but I don't understand why it was printing out so many bytes when the variable **buff** has shorts in it. At that point I was just printing the hex as %x, not %04x, and **buff** was not initialized to 0. Today, I decided to initialize it to 0 and not only did the garbage disappear, but I can't recreate the problem even after leaving **buff** uninitialized again.

So here are my questions that hopefully aren't too abstract:

1. Does fread look beyond the file when reading data and does it remove trailing garbage itself, or is it up to us?
2. Why was printf showing an int when the buffer is a short? (I assume %x is for ints) and why can't I replicate the behaviour even after leaving **buff** without initialization?
3. Should I always initialize the buffer to zero to remove trailing garbage? What's the usual approach here?

I hope these aren't too many, or too vague, questions, and that I was clear enough. Like I said, I don't know much about C but find low-mid level programming very interesting, especially when it comes to direct data bit/byte manipulation.

Hope you have a great day!

EDIT 1:
Some of you wisely suggested I use **num_read** instead of **nmemb** on the loop, since that's the return value of fread, but that means I'll discard the rest of the file (**nmemb** is 22 but **num_read** is 21). Is that the usual approach? Also, thank you for pointing out that %x was casting to unsigned int, hence the 4 bytes instead of 2.

EDIT 2:
For clarification, and since I mispoke in a comment, I'd like to keep the remaining byte (or data), while discarding the rest, which is undefined. I don't know if this is the usual approach since if I use **num_read** in the loop, whatever is leftover at the end is discarded, data or not. I'm more interested in knowing what the usual approach is: discard leftover data or remove anything that we know is undefined, in this case one of the bytes.

Comment: How do you want to treat the last remainder bytes?

Comment: Seems to me your loop should be based on `num_read`, not `nmemb`.

Comment: Since %x takes an unsigned int it'll cast your signed short to an int via sign extension, which means that the sign bit (most significant bit) will be used to fill the blank space. Ince your short was 0x9567, the sign bit is set, which means the empty space will be filled with 1s, leading to 0xffff9567. You won't see the 0xffff if you use unsigned shorts.

Comment: @MikeCAT Just discard, since they're not data from the file itself. C seems to do it for me, as long as I initialize the array to zero, which is why I assume the garbage is from the unitialized buffer and not from fread, but I'm not sure, as I don't know how fread itself works

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<nmemb; i++)` should be `for (int i=0; i<num_read; i++)` to use only actually read data and avoid dealing with (printing) uninitialized part of the buffer. Using values of uninitialized non-static local variables, whose values are indeterminate, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: That will result in losing the last byte, 0x67, since fread started going beyond the file, but still included some file data. Do you usually discard the end of the file then? To avoid undefined behaviour

Comment: `fread()` behaves as documented. Otherwise, many people would have complained the last 40 years.